# Why building with IL2CPP backend results in bigger apk size in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 2018.2.3 with .Net 4.6 Scripting Runtime.
I have two games. When I build with IL2CPP backend, apk size is always bigger than Mono backend.

First Game:
APK size With Mono: 12.9 MB
APK size with IL2CPP: 13.7 MB

Second Game:
APK size With Mono: 39 MB
APK size with IL2CPP: 45 MB

Why is this happening?

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that the Mono scripting backend is being deprecated and only the IL2CPP scripting backend will be available in the future.  So you should start planning for that change now.

Comment: @slaphshot33324 Does it mean that every time I want to test the game on actual device I have to wait 30+ minutes?

Comment: 30+ minutes for what?  What is taking 30+ minutes?

Comment: @slaphshot33324 The builds with IL2CPP backend take too much time (depending on size of project). If Mono build takes 5 minute, IL2CPP takes 30 minutes. It's horrible when you are trying to debug something on actual device.

Comment: 30 minutes seems like a rather long time. We're working on improving IL2CPP build times now, would be willing to share your project via bug report? We would love to understand why it is taking so long.

Comment: @JoshPeterson It has been a long time since we didn't use il2cpp backend in our project. We simply decided to not use it since it was increasing build time and final output size for no/small benefits. However we have the project on git. I will try to find the revision of the project that used il2cpp and will submit a bug report.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens for a few reasons.

First, the Android build with Mono ships the managed assemblies in the APK. Those assemblies are just-in-time compiled to machine code on the Android device. IL2CPP, on the other hand, ahead-of-time compiles the managed assemblies into machine code, and ships the machine code in the APK. The IL byte code in those managed assemblies is more compact than machine code for two reasons:

1. Only the managed code that is actually executed is converted to machine code by the JIT. IL2CPP must convert all of it.
2. Generics need to all be expanded ahead of time. IL2CPP can share some generic implementations, but not all (specifically not generic implementations with value type arguments). The JIT only generated the generic implementations as they are used.

Second, by default Unity generates machine code for both the ARMv7 and x86 architectures with IL2CPP. Since IL2CPP needs to generate that code ahead of time, all of the issues with larger code mentioned in the first point are duplicated. If you don't need to support x86, for example, you can modify the player settings to avoid building it.